# How does checkpointing work in HDFS? I would like to get clarity on fs.checkpoint.period and fs.checkpoint.size

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

When it says that , The secondary namenode checkpoints every hour (fs.checkpoint.period in seconds) or sooner if the edit log has reached 64 MB (fs.checkpoint.size in bytes) ? What does exactly in mean?

As per my understanding , edit logs gets stored in local file disk.

Comment: Have you read http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Checkpoint_Node ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HDFS metadata can be thought of consisting of two parts:  the base filesystem table (stored in a file called `fsimage`) and the edit log which lists changes made to the base table (stored in a file called `edits`).  Checkpointing is a process of reconciling `fsimage` with `edits` to produce a new version of `fsimage`.  There are two benefits arising out of this:  a more recent version of `fsimage`, and a truncated edit log.

`fs.checkpoint.period` controls how often this reconciliation will be triggered.  `3600` means that every hour `fsimage` will be updated and edit log truncated.  Checkpiont is not cheap, so there is a balance between running it too often and letting the edit log grow too large.  This parameter should be set to get a good balance assuming typical filesystem use in your cluster.

`fs.checkpoint.size` is a size threshold, which, if reached by `edits`, will trigger an immediate checkpoint regardless of time elapsed since the last checkpoint.  This is insurance from edit log getting too large under unusually heavy write traffic to the filesystem metadata.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. That explains quite a lot of thing.But I have one small query. What do you mean by base filesystem table?Is that the number of base filesystem tables are constant?If new base table gets created in the process , then won't then that metadata will get directly written into the fsimage directly ?

Comment: So what I have read, if I am not wrong, that this checkpointing is being done by secondary name node?

Comment: The primary namenode does not write back the most up to date version of `fsimage` to disk to maximize throughput while guaranteeing consistency.  This work is typically offloaded to the secondary namenode (your intuition is correct here), which must recreate the new `fsimage` from the older version + most recent edit log.

Answer (score 0):

NameNode maintains namespace in HDFS. All DataNode file metadata is stored in editLog and fsImage at NameNode. 
fsImage is an image of HDFS filesystem of a given time which is the accumulation of all changes happened to the cluster.
editLog contains the most recent changes. 
Checkpointing is the process to merge editLog into fsImage. This process is resource intensive and it can impact ongoing request at NameNode.

Secondary NameNode does checkpointing for HDSF NameNode.
It makes an HTTP request to NameNode and gets the latest fsImage logs and merge it with recent changes captured in editLogs.
Primary NameNode requests and Secondary NameNode replies with merged fsImage and editLog is truncated.

This is an event-driven process where an event is triggered based on any of these conditions:
1) A specific period in seconds fs.checkpoint.period 
2) An editLog reaches to specific size fs.checkpoint.size

Any of them can be configured in core-default.xml.
This should be set optimal based on available network bandwidth as well as accumulation of changes can happen over specified time.

Answer (score 0):

Name node , master node of HDFS, contains all the metadata information. It is important to keep this meta data information up to date.

When any changes are made on the data, corresponding metadata has to be changed. But during run time, name node cannot directly do these changes on the fly, instead these are stored in log files. During next start up, all the previous changes are collected from the logs(edits file) and applied to the existing metadata (fsimage file) and the result is uploaded back in Hadoop .
If there are huge logs it takes time to apply these changes and make it ready for next start up. Check point node solves this problem.

Checkpoint node helps this process of applying any changes to metadata during run time itself. It periodically checks for any logs apply the same to the existing state of metadata and uploads the result to name node.

Secondary name node also does the same job, but the result is not sent back to name node.